# Save custom frontend form data to database magento 2.4.5

Tags: layout, blocks, controllers, crud, frontend-model

I have created custom form on frontend and now on submit click I want to save filled data to database.

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Crud_Contactmodule" setup_version='1.0.2'> 
   <sequence>
    <module name="Magento_Directory" />
    <module name="Magento_Config" />
  </sequence>
</module>
```

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
 <router id="standard">
  <route id="contactform" frontName="contactform">
   <module name="Crud_Contactmodule" />
  </route>
 </router>
</config>
```

**Controller**

````
<?php
namespace Crud\Contactmodule\Controller\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  protected $_pageFactory;
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
  {
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
  }
  public function execute()
  {
    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
   
  }
}```
````

**Block**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Crud\Contactmodule\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

/**
 * Main contact form block
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class ContactForm extends Template
{
    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Template\Context $context, array $data = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns action url for contact form
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFormAction()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('contactForm/Index/Index', ['_secure' => true]);
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="custom-form">

  <form action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" id="custom-form" method="post">

    <fieldset class="fieldset">
      <legend class="legend"><span><?php  echo __("Contact Form") ?></span></legend><br />


      <div class="field name required">

        <label class="label" for="name"><span><?php  echo __('Name') ?></span></label>

        <div class="control">

          <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php  echo __('Name') ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>

        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="field email required">

        <label class="label" for="email"><span><?php  echo __('Email') ?></span></label>

        <div class="control">

          <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php  echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>

        </div>

      </div>



      <div class="field telephone">

        <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?php  echo __('Phone Number') ?></span></label>

        <div class="control">

          <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php  echo __('Phone Number') ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />

        </div>

      </div>



    </fieldset>

    <div class="actions-toolbar">

      <div class="primary">


        <button type="submit" title="<?php  echo __('Submit') ?>" class="action submit primary" id="custom_btn">

          <span><?php  echo __('Submit') ?></span>

        </button>

      </div>

    </div>

  </form>

</div>
```

and form load like this on frontend

[image]

Now I want that whenever user fill form data and clicks on submit, the data should be saved in database, for that which controller and class I have to use, I confused because whenever I remove this `return $this->_pageFactory->create();` from controller and write code for fetch submitted data the page does not load.

Comment: where is your layout file?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Crud\Contactmodule\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Crud_Contactmodule::contact.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>

Answer (score 0):

You need to create other controller for save data in db like below example,and then change the action in block 'contactForm/Index/Index' => 'contactform/index/save' and change the Model path in Save controller that you use for db.

```
    <?php

namespace VenderName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use VenderName\ModuleName\Model\FormFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface as HttpPostActionInterface;

class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action implements HttpPostActionInterface
{
    protected $_formFactory;
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        FormFactory $formFactory
    ) {
        $this->_formFactory = $formFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $post_data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        try {
            $data = $this->_formFactory->create();
            $data->setData($post_data);
            $data->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__("Save Data"));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('please try again. Form Not Submit'));
        }
    }
}
```